# Guidance to solve margin problems in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

Can anyone give me a guidance to solve margin problems? 
I am new in XAML. i have confused with left, top and right, bottom

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Refer this MSDN Documentation:

[Framework Element Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Margin is set by left,top,right,bottom
You can either set a value for all angles or specify each one.

```
//SETS A MARGIN OF 10px in all four directions
<Grid margin="10"></Grid>

//SETS A 10px margin left, 15px margin top, 10px margin right and 15px bottom 
<Grid margin="10, 15, 10, 15"></grid>
```